# Не работает команда Cmd в адресной строке проводника

Tags: windows, cmd, администрирование

При вводе команды Cmd в адресную строку проводника Windows 10 вызывается ошибка:
"Указанный путь не существует.
Исправьте его или повторите попытку."
Как исправить этот путь? В интернете ответа не нашел.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а с меню win+r удается запустить?

Comment: С win + r, да удается

Comment: я попробовал в проводнике - заработало. Никогда так даже не думал, что оно работает.